# Using modal from semantic ui

Tags: dart

I am planing to use semantic ui [modal](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html) has anyone any idea, how to interoperate with dart?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [js package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) to interoperate. First, add the package as a dependency. Then, wrap the JavaScript that you want to use from Dart. Here's an example allowing you to use jQuery's `$(...).addClass(...)` in Dart:

```
@JS()
library jquery;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

// Calls invoke JavaScript `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
@JS("\$")
external ElementSet $(String selector);

@JS()
class ElementSet {
  external addClass(String className);
}
```

If you import this file, you can now do:

```
$('#output').addClass("red");
```

That example is, of course, quite useless — Dart already allows you to modify HTML classes with better readability and flexibility (e.g. `querySelector('#output').classes.add("red")`).

But in your case, it starts to make sense. You would implement `modal()` and go from there.

(I would give you an example of how to implement modal, but I wasn't able to install semantic ui on my workstation for 10+ minutes and then I gave up. So I used the `jQuery.addClass` example instead.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy. There are two or three pub packages available but they are outdated and incomplete.

I did it this way in **Dart 2** (AngularDart 5):

```
import 'dart:js';

// somewhere in the component:
context
  .callMethod(r'$', [modalSelector])
  .callMethod('modal', [new JsObject.jsify({
    'onApprove': new JsFunction.withThis((element){
      // do something on approve
    })
  })])
  .callMethod('modal', ['show']);
```

This Dart code is equivalent to this Javascript code:

```
$(modalSelector).modal({
    'onApprove': function(element){
      // do something on approve
    })
    .modal('show');
```

As you may see, you have to call the jQuery framework through the JS module.